# I am not able to complete this loop perfectly

Tags: c, algorithm

write a program to enter five marks and by taking its average percent to determine the grade(only using nested if else) by following conditions:
if 90 and above: grade A
if 80-70: grade B
if 70-80: grade C
if 50-70: grade D
if below 50: fail

I did try the loop starting from backward by using if(avg>=50) but it did not give me the desired output because it will always be stuck at you failed which I kept it in else condition.

```
if ( avg <= 90 )
{
    if ( avg <= 80 )
    {
        if ( avg <= 70 )
        {
            if ( avg <= 50 )
            {
                printf( "Fail" );
            }
            else
            {
                printf( "D" );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "C" );
        }
    }
    else  
    {
        printf( "B" );
    }
}
else  
{
    printf( "A" );
}
```

If I enter marks above 90 then I expect the output to come A but instead it comes you have "failed"

Comment: Can you provide the full code?

Comment: With `int avg = 90` your code prints A as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
int main()
{
    int marks[5];
    int i,j;
    float avg;
    int total=0;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&marks[i]);
    }
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        total = total+marks[j];
    }

    avg = total/5;

if(avg<50)
{
    printf("Fail");
}
  else
  {
      if(avg>=50 &&avg<70)
      {
          printf("C");
      }

        else if(avg>=70)
        {
            if(avg>=80)
            {
                if(avg<90)
                {
                    printf("B");
                }
                else if (avg>=90)
                {
                    printf("A");
                }
            }

        }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to include `if(avg>=50 &&` inside the `else`, the `else` already covers that. Also, your chain for 70-80-90 is confusing and prone to mistakes. Check out Umar's answer for the clean way of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

You should try using else if ladder

```
if(avg>=90)
{
 printf("A");
}
else if(avg>=80)
    {
     printf("B");
    }
else if(avg>=70)
    {
     printf("C");
    }
else if(avg>=50)
    {
     printf("D");
    }
else{ 
     printf("Fail");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think `switch` statement may be the best solution.

```
# include <stdio.h>

const char * mark(int grade){
    switch (grade/10){
        case 10:
        case 9:
            return "A";
        case 8:
            return "B";
        case 7:
        case 6:
        case 5:
            return "C";
        default:
            return "Fail";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int grade;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i){
        if (sscanf(argv[i], "%d", &grade) < 1){
            fprintf(stderr, "\"%s\" can not be converted to an int.\n", argv[i]);
            return -1;
        }else{
            printf("%s\n", mark(grade));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```